# Is the "Strunk & White" badge not given anymore?

Tags: support, badges

I have noticed that [Laxman13](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/320/laxman13) has gained the "[Strunk & White](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white)" badge, but [googletorp](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/190/googletorp), with more than 80 edits, didn't get it. Why?

Is the badge not assigned anymore?

The reason I am asking is that I edited one of my posts, and then checked the number of edits reported for me, which was not changed. I would take my own edits are not counted, in the page of the editors.

Comment: Note that edits to posts you own and tag edits (to any post) don't count. So estimating someone's progress toward the badge can be tricky...

Comment: @ Shog9 Does that mean the number of edits shows in the "editors" page counts all the edits, including the ones that count toward getting the badge? If it so, then that is the answer to my question. `:-)`

Comment: Right, all edits including your own I think.  I believe I got the badge when I was at ~92 edits on the "editors" page

Comment: @Laxman13 I got confused because once I edited one post of mine, and checked the number of edits reported for me, which didn't increase. The problem is that the number of edits is not immediately increased, and I thought that edits on your own posts were not counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badge is still being given out, we haven't cycled it out or anything.

The number of edits shown on the editors tab includes a variety of edits that do not count towards getting the badge. As such, if that is your only measure for someone hitting 80 edits, it may be inaccurate.