# How to get Strunk & White badge?

Tags: discussion

I had 84 approved suggested edit, see the below image
, but still not able to get the **Strunk & White** badge.

[image]

**How to get Strunk & White badge ?**

It clearly mentioned for 80 Edits, but not sure for which 80 Edits ? See the below image and from this post [Is the "Strunk & White" badge not given anymore?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/490/is-the-strunk-white-badge-not-given-anymore) - i understand not for the own post edit, so the badge for suggested edit, then why the badge not awarded ?.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those 84 suggested edits that were accepted includes the suggested edits for posts that has been then deleted. If you look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=activity&sort=suggestions, you will notice it says you have 95 suggested edits, not 110 (84 + 26).

[image: screenshot]

Since you loses the reputation gained from suggested edits when the post is delete, I get that those suggested edits are not even counted to get the badge. See your reputation where it shows something similar to the following.

[image: screenshot]

That is what you see when a post for which you suggested an edit that has been approved is deleted. It should not be confused from an entry like the following, which is about reputation you gain back from a down-vote once you delete the down-voted post.

[image: screenshot]

Even with just the first entry, the meaning would be clear: You got back reputation because a deleted post. (The background is different and the description says "removed.") The only way to get a -2 on a post is from a down-vote you get.

If you don't get the badge, I take that is the reason. Otherwise, it's only a delay in getting it, since cron tasks that check the users who gained badges run at different times. Some checks are done more frequently than others; it all depends on their computational cost.

Answer (score 0):

Badges are awarded by the CRON script, so the time you need to wait to get one after you deserved it may vary. If it exceeds 24 hours it's time to worry.

Comment: more than a week

Comment: Strange. To clarify - were some of your edits just retags? Or all of the accepted 80 was "real" edits?

Comment: all are real edits http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=activity