# How can a user get 'Strunk & White' Badge whose suggested edits are below 80?

Tags: support, badges

How did this [user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7372/anil-sagar?tab=activity) got [Strunk & White](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) badge as his suggested edits are below 80 ?

As of my understand, every user need to have at least 80 'suggested edits' to get this badge.

I got some knowledge on this badge from the following posts.

[How to get Strunk & White badge?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/how-to-get-strunk-white-badge)

[Is the “Strunk & White” badge not given anymore?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/490/is-the-strunk-white-badge-not-given-anymore)

Did I miss any thing to understand about this badge?

Comment: Not only suggested edit, the count is also for normal edit to the post! After 2000 rep users no need to wait in review queue, their edit will appear immediately. So anil made more than that, suggested edit only count if user below 2000K rep.

Comment: @Bala  - Great! thanks bala, now it's clear. So after 2k reputation, user can't able to see their edits under his 'suggested edits' tab, right?

Comment: Yes suggested edits are only for < 2k users only!.

Comment: @Bala - Thanks bala, it's clear now. When you have time please make your comment as answer.There is typo in your first comment. ( 2k not 2000k) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edits count is not only for suggested edits, but also for normal edits. Once their reputation reach 2000, users don't need to suggest edits; their edits directly apply to the posts they change.

That is the case of Anil Sagar.